# Is there a way to see a record of edits to a file via CMD?

Tags: cmd

I have a log file (specifically a Python file) that I want to keep an eye on.  This file needs to be editable through a program, so I cannot deny permissions, so I'm wondering if there is a way I can get a history of the recent edits to this file?  If there is, how can it be done?

I'm picturing something like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but for CMD (that one is for Visual Studios)

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, thanks in advance!

Comment: There are operating systems that keep track on changes of a file - windows does not. Your only chance is to do it yourself (copying on a regualar basis and check differences)

Comment: It sounds like you need a Version Control System like [Git](http://git-scm.com/)